# Ubuntu 14.04 boot error Black screen | Solution

Tags: boot

So I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and on my first boot I got this error:

```
The system is running in low-graphics mode
```

I tried following the steps from: [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I got to the terminal, logged in and used the command "sudo apt-get install fglrx". Then after reboot I just got a black screen and could do nothing but physically restart the computer. Then I restarted and pressed F11 and I got into 'GRUB'.

In the GRUB I chose "Ubuntu, with Linux...Recovery Mode and then selected failsafeX, but then once again I just get a black screen and can do nothing.

UPDATE:
I made a new clean installation of Ubuntu 14.04 now from same ISO file as before. Now I can reboot it perfectly but ofcourse my stuff is gone. What I had installed before: apache2 server and ffmpeg, can anyone of those cause the problem above?

**SOLUTION**
After a nights sleep I booted my new installation and I got the same error, however this post(which I cant find the original of atm so I just type it all here) fixed it for me:

"Follow these commands:
`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get -d install --reinstall gdm`

`sudo apt-get remove --purge gdm`

`sudo apt-get install gdm`

Select GDM when prompted

`sudo reboot`"

Comment: What is the content of your `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf ` file?